# New chain 'jumps' on sprocket

Tags: chain, derailleur-rear, campagnolo

- Campagnolo Triple T rear derailleur 9 Speed
- Campagnolo Athena 3x11 speed crank and front derailleur
- Chain KMC X11 with missing link.
  [http://www.kmcchain.eu/chain-KMC_X11–93-road_cross-11_speed](http://www.kmcchain.eu/chain-KMC_X11%E2%80%9393-road_cross-11_speed)

The new chain jumps on the sprocket, it goes very fast and I can really see where it happens, but think it does not jump to an other sprocket but somehow on the spocket itself. It only occurs when I pedal with a lot of power and only on the smaller sized sprocket.

Edit:
 [image: Image of Missing Link and sprocket.]

Comment: Spoke and sprocket are different things. Chain should not touch spokes. Spockets are not a thing. That being said, if you didn't replace the cassette, it's probably worn out and needs replacing too.

Comment: See [this answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/45275/30916) why mixing new and worn-out parts (new chain/old cassette, new cassette/old chain) lead to a jumping chain.

Comment: @Paparazzi that suggested dupe is about the cassette rotating on the splines of the freehub.  Penta probably needs to change cassette as well as chain, and ASAP else the new chain will wear much faster.

Comment: The "where it happens" line makes me think of a possibly stiff link. Try flexing the chain laterally to see if you have one. It should bend relatively freely.

Comment: You may find https://www.sheldonbrown.com/chain-wear.html helpful in understanding what is going on

Comment: @Batman: Stiff links are common when the fresh rivet binds. But since this is a KMC assembled with a 'missing link' it seems rather unlikely.

Comment: The cassette does not look like it is worn-out. But please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Hard to say, but I've had slippage on a "lightly used" cassette as soon as I changed the chain.  I think you want to ride as little as possible in those slippy gears until you get a new cassette.  A cheap shimano 9 speed one should be $15-$30 USD, but I'm not sure if you'll have any compatibility problems with campo stuff.

Comment: @Penta it is worn out, you are welcome. The shark fin shaped teeth are a giveaway.

Comment: @Criggie Shimano cassettes don't fit on Campagnolo freehub bodies. You need a Campagnolo one.

Comment: The cassette does not appear to be seriously worn.  I'm guessing that either the chain is too narrow or the derailer is not centering over the cogs correctly.  Or perhaps the chain length is the issue.  Hard to tell from the single picture.

Comment: Both small sprockets look rather worn. The smallest has different sized 'valleys' between the teeth.